# how to display json_encoded data from the CI controller in ajax with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to display json_encoded data sending by the CI controller

```
public function single_member_info(){
    $selected_id=$this->input->post('selectedid');
    $data['member_data']=$this->db->get_where('member',array('member_id'=>$selected_id))->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Json data display in the ajax success section indivisually(i want to access json data one by one)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.show_data').click(function(){
          var selected_id=$(this).attr('id');
          $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: '<?php echo base_url()?>Welcome/single_member_info',
                  data: {selectedid:selected_id},
                  success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                }
          });
      });
});
```

in console output like this

```
{"member_data":[{"member_id":"2","member_profile_id":"BD446F49452","status":"approved","first_name":"nagendra","last_name":"ks","gender":"1","email":"nagenfg@gmail.com","mobile":"8558453046","alternative_mobile":"","is_closed":"no","date_of_birth":"74884479200","height":"5.40","password":"7c4a8d09ca3744588562af61e59520943dc26494f8941b","profile_image":"[{\"profile_image\":\"profile_2.png\",\"thumb\":\"profile_2_thumb.png\"}]"}
```

Comment: Loop through `data.member_data` and display it however you require.

Comment: Use JSON.parse();

Comment: If you want to use it as array than first use `JSON.parse` otherwise @RoryMcCrossan mention the better way

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh if the content type of the response is set correctly you shouldn't need to use `JSON.parse`; jQuery will do it automatically for you

Comment: Yes you are right @Robin but content type is not mentioned so and yes RoryMcCrossan is also right.
Upvoted both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.show_data').click(function(){
          var selected_id=$(this).attr('id');
          $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: '<?php echo base_url()?>Welcome/single_member_info',
                  data: {selectedid:selected_id},
                  success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].member_data+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }

               }
          });
      });
});


     $('#show_data').html(html);
```

Comment: where you get undefined ?

Comment: in this line                html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].member_data+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>';